# Top value by criteria and order

Tags: filter, max, powerbi, dax, rank

I'm trying to calculate the maximum value with multiple conditions and order in Power BI.

I've called the function to create a column with the top1 by Year, Branch, Group and Type disconsidering Company.

```
TOP1 = CALCULATE(MAX(data[Value]);
      FILTER(ALLEXCEPT(data;data[Company];
      data[Year] = data[Year] 
      && data[Branch] = data_segmento_anual[Branch]
      && data_segmento_anual[Group] = data_segmento_anual[Group]
      && data_segmento_anual[Bond] = data_segmento_anual[Bond]
      && data_segmento_anual[Type] = data_segmento_anual[Type]))
```

Then the result:

```
YEAR    COMPANY         BRANCH  GROUP     Value     TOP1
2016    BANCO DO BRASIL RISK    RETAIL    4061567   4061567
2016    BANCO DO BRASIL ACUM    RETAIL    1901920   1901920
2017    BANCO DO BRASIL RISK    CORPORATE 439499    439499
2017    BANCO DO BRASIL RISK    RETAIL    356231    356231
2016    BRADESCO        RISK    CORPORATE 347369    347369
2016    BANCO DO BRASIL RISK    RETAIL    310920    4061567
2016    BANCO DO BRASIL ACUM    CORPORATE 12091     12091
2016    BANCO DO BRASIL RISK    RETAIL    1021      4061567
2017    BANCO DO BRASIL RISK    CORPORATE 446       439499
```

But I want to insert another column that would be the second, third, fifith ... greater value and so on. The result would be:

```
YEAR    COMPANY         BRANCH  GROUP     Value   TOP1    TOP2
2016    BANCO DO BRASIL RISK    RETAIL    4061567 4061567 310920
2016    BANCO DO BRASIL ACUM    RETAIL    1901920 1901920 NA
2017    BANCO DO BRASIL RISK    CORPORATE 439499  439499  446
2017    BANCO DO BRASIL RISK    RETAIL    356231  356231  NA
2016    BRADESCO        RISK    CORPORATE 347369  347369  NA
2016    BANCO DO BRASIL RISK    RETAIL    310920  4061567 310920
2016    BANCO DO BRASIL ACUM    CORPORATE 12091   12091   NA
2016    BANCO DO BRASIL RISK    RETAIL    1021    4061567 310920
2017    BANCO DO BRASIL RISK    CORPORATE 446     439499  446
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Earlier()` function in calculated columns to reference the current row's value.

See how the following two calculated columns complete your requirements (you will need to change the names to fit your dataset):

```
V2 = CALCULATE(max(Test[V1]),
FILTER(all(Test),
Test[V1] < earlier(Test[V1]) 
&& EARLIER(Test[C2]) = Test[C2] 
&& EARLIER(Test[C3]) = Test[C3]))
```

_

```
V3 = CALCULATE(max(Test[V2]),
FILTER(all(Test),
Test[V2] < earlier(Test[V2]) 
&& EARLIER(Test[C2]) = Test[C2] 
&& EARLIER(Test[C3]) = Test[C3]))
```

[image: Example]